# Subject + am/is/are + to + verb

Tags: modality

Could anybody clear it to me whether these two sentence are grammatically equal? If not, what is the difference?

> 1) They must use some methods...
>  
>   2) They are to use some methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [modal verb *must*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/must_1) in this sentence denotes that using some methods is *completely necessary* or *very important*.

On the other hand, *are to* talks about their likelihood to use some methods.

This said,

> They ***must*** use some methods - they should use some methods, it's utterly necessary.

and...

> The ***are to*** use some methods - it's likely that they will use some methods.

Answer (score 1):

> 1- They **must** use some methods...

is a requirement.

> 2- They **are to** use some methods...

is an instruction or expectation.